# Table error: Illegal pream-token ([):'c' used

Tags: tables, tabulary

I am having a problem of this:

```
 Illegal pream-token ([):'c' used.
```

I suspect is this:

```
   lSl[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]}
```

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  lSl[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]}
\toprule
{\textbf{Sample Number}}
& 
& {\textbf{Testing 123 Testing}} \\
\midrule
ABC &  $\rightarrow$  &  {sample testing [ , ]} \\
ABCS &  $\rightarrow$  &  {sample testing testing testing [ , ]} \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, you have a stray `l` character in `\begin{tabular}{lSl[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]}`. Change it to `\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]}` to get rid of this error.

Comment: @Mico, thanks. But I have 3 column in my table. It still have error.

Comment: In that case, move the `l` character from before to *after* `S[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]`.

Comment: @Mico. thanks, it works. Sorry for my ignorance. Can you explain in simple text what is that meaning?

Comment: The `l` column type means "left-aligned contents". The `S` column type should be used for aligning numbers on their decimal markers. As you have (hopefully) discovered, the `S` column type can take an optional argument -- the material between square brackets -- bu the `l` column type does not.

Comment: Incidentally, I have absolutely no idea why you would ever use the `S` column type to typeset `\rightarrow`. Why aren't you using either the `c` ("centered") or the `l` column type for the second column?

Comment: @Mico Because I used other table template. I edit and use the implies `\begin{tabular}{lcl}` and it works too

Comment: `S` type columns are only useful for columns that contain numbers.

Comment: @aan - Please don't feel I'm attacking you unjustly, but a lot of the questions you ask on this site seem to betray a serious lack of understanding of LaTeX fundamentals. Please do yourself a big favor and take a few hours to work through the document [The not so short introduction to LaTeX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) by T. Oetiker et al. I'm sure you'll find it time very well spent. For instance, you'll know immediately what's wrong with `\begin{tabular}{lSl[table-format=2.2,table-space-text-post=\%]}` -- and will thus have less need to post queries on TeX.SE ...

Comment: Since you mention using "other table templates": Please be aware that ther is no "table template"  that fits perfectly for every table you could have. You have to write the code for a table on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @ thanks. It really help.